# What is $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} z \cdot \sin|(\frac{1}{z})|$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

What is $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} z \cdot \sin|(\frac{1}{z})|$ for $z \in \mathbb C^*$?

I tried solving this in the same way as $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} z \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{z})$ by finding limit along x and y axis separately. How to solve $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{x^{2}})$ which I got after opening the modulus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|z|$ and $\sin(\frac{1}{|z|})$ are real, we have

$\lim\limits_{z \to 0} |z| \cdot \sin|(\frac{1}{z})|=0$, hence $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} z \cdot \sin|(\frac{1}{z})|=0.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

1. For real values of $x$, $\sin(x)$ is bounded on $[-1,1]$
2. $\left|\frac1z\right|$ is a real number.

Comment: (+1) That was fast! ;-)